# wcf service returning derived type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

I have a following sample wcf service (using webHttpBinding):

```
[ServiceContract]
public class Animals {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{id}")]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Dog))]
    public Animal GetAnimalById(string id) {
        switch (id) {
            case "1": return new Animal { Id = 1 };
            case "2": return new Dog { Id = 2 };
        }
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Types are defined as follows:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Dog))]
public class Animal {
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When 1 is supplied, the xml retured from the service is (xmlns omitted for brevity):

```
<Animal><Id>1</Id><Name i:nil="true"/></Animal>
```

When 2 is supplied:

```
<Dog><Id>2</Id><Name i:nil="true"/></Dog>
```

And here is the question: **Why can't DataContractSerializer constructed for Animal deserialize second xml?** It throws something like: Expecting element 'Animal' from namespace 'bla bla'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Dog', namespace 'bla bla'.

Additional information:
 1. If I construct DataContractSerializer supplying typeof(Dog) as parameter it obviously work.
 2. If I construct DataContractSerializer supplying typeof(Animal) as parameter (cause I don't know the type of object I'm about to serialize / deserialize) and then serialize Dog the xml will look like this:

```
<Animal i:type="Dog"><Id>0</Id><Name i:nil="true"/></Animal>
```

Which can in turn be deserialized using same serializer without any problem. Can I force WCF to serialize using DataContractSerializer supplied with base type rather than derived (which seems more reasonable and probably should be there by default anyway)?

Answer (score 4):

Use the ServiceKnownType on **interface** of your service instead on the class Animal.

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Dog))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAnimals 
{
  public Animal GetAnimalById(string id);
}

public class Animals : IAnimals { [your original code] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because WCF is passing structured XML data, and not a types. WCF is not object-oriented. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751512.aspx

You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx if you want to, or create a custom one.

Comment: I'm not sure you noticed @Jocke, but I do apply KnownType to Dog class, and it works, it gets serialized (but as Dog and not as <Animal i:type="Dog"> which would make more sense given signature of the service). As for the second link you send, I do want to use DataContractSerializer.